# Best way to call a classes method with spl_autoloader()

Tags: php, oop, autoloader

I wonder whats the best way to call a classes method when using autoloader. 
This is what I got:

// Index.php

```
<?php
  require_once('./c_main.php');
  spl_autoload_register('Main::loader');
?>
<title>INDEX</title>
<body>
  <?php
    echo Test::getText();
  ?>
</body>
```

// c_main.php

// /classes/c_test.php

```
<?php

class Test {

    PUBLIC function getText() { return Storage::getText(); }

}

?>
```

// classes/c_storage.php

```
class Storage {

    PUBLIC function getText() { return "AUTOLOADER WORKS!"; }

}

?>
```

Output is: "AUTOLOADER WORKS!"

My Question: As you can see, I called `getText()` with `Storage::getText()`.
I don't think that this is the way I should work, it doesnt feel OOP like. Is there a better way I should use?

Thanks in advance!

Philip

Comment: This doesnt really have much to do with autoloading, this has to do with when/why to use static methods or not and by extension dependency injection and those types of things. Also your specific question is a little broad as it partially depends on what the intent of the classes are and the design of the system.

Comment: well for instance I got a class that loads data from a database and a class that formats output. I just want to know whether I should build an instance from `class Format` so I can use: `$this->Format->formatOutput($databaseContent)` or if `Format::formatOutput($databaseContent)` is a good style? I think I should avoid accesses like `Class::Method` because its not oop like, right?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, although typically you dont want you db class to do anything with formatting - it should only care about interacting with the db.

Comment: well i gets the results, like: `$output = Database::select('*', 'from')` `echo Format::formatOutput($output);`